# foreach value format_price

Tags: php, foreach, number-formatting

**HTML form**

```
<form action="createpdf.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="title[]" />
    <input type="text" name="unit_price[]" />
    <input type="text" name="item_quantity[]" />
    <input type="text" name="total_cost[]" />
        // etc...
</form>
```

now send me inserted values to *createpdf.php*

**PHP code for TCPDF converting HTML to PDF / createpdf.php**

```
$html = 'something...';

foreach($_POST['title'] as $key => $v1){
    $html = $html.'
        <tr>
            <td>'.$_POST['item_title'][$key].'</td>
            <td>'.$_POST['unit_price'][$key].'</td>
            <td>'.$_POST['item_quantity'][$key].'</td>
            <td>'.$_POST['total_cost'][$key].'</td>
        </tr>
    ';}

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

**Target**

Is there anybody, who can tell me how can I use the following function which should format values before POSTing data to table cells? I need this pattern  **x xxx.dd**  and just don't know how... Thanks a lot

```
function format_price($number,$decPlaces,$decSep,$thouSep){

    //$number - number for format
    //$decPlaces - number of decimal places
    //$decSep - separator for decimals
    //$thouSep - separator for thousands

    //first remove all white spaces
    $number=preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$number);
    //split string into array
    $numberArr = str_split($number);
    //reverse array and not preserve key, keys will help to find decimal place
    $numberArrRev=array_reverse($numberArr);

    //find first occurrence of non number character, that will be a decimal place
    //store $key into variable $decPointIsHere 
    foreach ($numberArrRev as $key => $value) {
        if(!is_numeric($value)){
            if($decPointIsHere==""){
                $decPointIsHere=$key;
            }            
        }
    }

    //decimal comma or whatever it is replace with dot
    //$decPointIsHere is the key of the element that will contain decimal separator dot 
    if($decPointIsHere!=""){
        $numberArrRev[$decPointIsHere]=".";
    }

    //again check through array for non numerical characters but skipping allready processed keys
    //if is not number remove from array

    foreach ($numberArrRev as $key => $value) {
        if(!is_numeric($value) && $key>$decPointIsHere){
            unset($numberArrRev[$key]);            
        }
    }

    //reverse back, at the start reversed array $numberArrRev to $numberArr
    $numberArr=array_reverse($numberArrRev);    

    //create string from array
    $numberClean=implode("",$numberArr);

    // apply php number_format function
    return number_format($numberClean,$decPlaces,$decSep,$thouSep);

}
```

Comment: whats wrong with number_format() ?

Comment: @Sidstar Probably nothing, but as a beginner don't know integrate this function before foreach.

Comment: to show x xxx.dd (or i.e. 1 234.56) why not use number_format($num, 2, ".", " ");

Comment: Ok I understand but could you, please, suggest me, where i have to use this function?

Comment: and how? because i really don't know, i've tried a million ways to format price, but with no success

Comment: Ok, thank you for voting down. You are master :-)

Comment: I didn't vote down. in fact I posted an answer!

Comment: Sorry that wasn't for you but for that unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
   <td>'.number_format($_POST['unit_price'][$key], 2, ".", " ").'</td>
```

Comment: I know, it's trifle for you, but not for me but I got it now and it seems easy...

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I'd think this should be it:

```
<td>' . format_price($_POST['unit_price'][$key],2,'.','') . '</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments tell you how to do it:

```
format_price($_POST['unit_price'][$key], 2, ".", " ");
```

Comment: Thank you Ed. Do you think, there is some difference before this function and number_format?

Comment: format_price() is a user defined function which I can see has to come down to number_format in the end when returning a result... number_format is one of PHP core functions... format_price is used by your scripts developer to ensure the string a properly clean (which I dont see is necessary unless there are some additional circumstances not visible here).

Comment: you can use format_price too, since its defined in your script already (I believe) and it will give the 100% same result.

Comment: The only difference is that your function seems to do some stripping of whitespace, but number_format will effectively do that, too. Practically speaking, there's really no reason not to use number_format. As @Sidstar says, format_price ultimately relies on number_format, anyway. The results should be the same.

Comment: I tried to use price_format
Call to undefined function price_format()
but I've define the function at the start of the script after library requiring

Comment: That's because the function is format_price, not price_format.

Comment: Fool :-)
format_price... Yeah, i've just noticed. Thanks a lot

Comment: Now it says: Undefined variable: decPointIsHere, line 22

   foreach ($numberArrRev as $key => $value) {
        if(!is_numeric($value)){
            if($decPointIsHere==""){
                $decPointIsHere=$key;
            }            
        }
    }

Comment: Anyway, I've reached my goal with number_format(). Thank you again

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it uses `$decPointIsHere` without ever defining it, which will report an error if you have error reporting turned on. Honestly, I'd just use [`number_format()`](http://us2.php.net/number_format) and save yourself the headache. :)